# Link to App in App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, hyperlink, app-store

I have 2 links to 2 different Apps in App Store: https: //codepen.io/Cr0up13r/pen/KXMGLL

On clicking on first link, new tab opens and I'm getting asked [Open this page in "App Store"?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zlgY.jpg). On clicking on second link, nothing happens. On tapping on this link for about 1-2 seconds, I'm getting a notification [Open in "App Store", Copy, Share... or Cancel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI18j.jpg). Why this different behaviour? What have I to do to open second link on click (like first link)? Thanks.

I'm using Safari / iPhone 6 / iOS 11.

Comment: just replace with this one https://appsto.re/de/MGZBfb

Try once. I have remove '.i' from given link & it's opening now.

Comment: thx a lot. why is **'.i'** there / what is the benefit of **'.i'** ?

Comment: no idea :) please check with any web guy.